# How to sort glossaries entries by alphabetical order then by order of appereance

Tags: glossaries, xindy

I would like my `glossaries` entries to be sorted by alphabetical order, and, if some entries have identical sort keys, by the order they are called in the text. Any way to do this ?

Here is the MWE, with the two entries `div` and `commut` exhibiting identical sort keys.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[
            nogroupskip,
%           xindy, 
            ]{glossaries}
% I compile with xindy, but I do not think it is relevant here.
% xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M % -t %.glg -o %.gls %.glo


\newglossaryentry{div}
{ name={\ensuremath{\protect\vec{\nabla}.}},
  description={Divergence operator},
  sort={0}
  }

\newglossaryentry{commut}
{ name={\ensuremath{\protect[~,~]}},
  description={Commutator},
  sort={0}
  }

\newglossaryentry{b0}
{ name={\ensuremath{\protect\vec{B}_0}},
  description={Static magnetic field},
  sort={B0}
  }

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
Text.\gls{div} \gls{commut} \gls{b0}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Here, for example, the commutator do not appear in the glossary. I would like to have it appearing after the divergence operator despite their identical sorting keys.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using `\makenoidxglossaries` together with `\printnoidxglossary[sort=standard]` which sorts the elements first according to the sort-key and then according to usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{div}
{ name={\ensuremath{\protect\vec{\nabla}.}},
  description={Divergence operator},
  sort={0}
  }

\newglossaryentry{commut}
{ name={\ensuremath{\protect[~,~]}},
  description={Commutator},
  sort={0}
  }

\newglossaryentry{b0}
{ name={\ensuremath{\protect\vec{B}_0}},
  description={Static magnetic field},
  sort={B0}
  }

\newglossaryentry{b1}
{ name={\ensuremath{\protect\vec{B}_1}},
  description={Static magnetic field},
  sort={B0}
  }

\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}
Text.\gls{b1} \gls{div} \gls{commut} \gls{b0}

\printnoidxglossary[sort=standard]
\end{document}
```

Then you get

[image]

First the `0` entries show up according to usage, then the two `B0` entries.

(`xindy` might change the entries for the sorting, so I'm not sure if it works there...)

Comment: This actually works quite nicely indeed. No especial problem with xindy, apparently. I just would like to wait a little more if someone come with another answer, like something that adds a number at the end of the "sort" part or something.

Comment: +1 I hadn't noticed that as a by-product of the pre-sorted list being ordered according to usage this would happen! @HcN I think this is the best solution. The makeindex/xindy options set the sort value when the entry is defined. (This isn't simply the value of the `sort` key but it has also had the makeindex/xindy special characters escaped.) If the `sort` value is later adjusted it's liable to cause clones of the entries with the modified value which will confuse makeindex/xindy. The first use flag can't be relied on in this context as it may have been reset.